# Run-time Error '13' Type Mismatch IF value = Then Statement loop

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

Basically what I'm doing is I have data in columns A-I and I'm trying to copy out data [Columns D-G] by their value in D. In this loop I'm looking for when the entry in D says "1CME Cash-Settled Butter".

I then starting in column K (=11) I paste it. Then I stack the rows.

The loop starts over and starts looking for a different value.

My problem is that I've ran the code fine for many runs. I haven't changed the code since, but now I'm getting Run-Time Error Type '13' Mismatch. Is there someway to fix this or write new code?

I'm just learning VBA!

Thanks!

```
iRow = 2
For Each i In Range("D2:D200")
    If i.Value = "1CME Cash-Settled Butter" Then
        Range(i.Offset(0, 0), i.Offset(0, 3)).Copy
        Cells(iRow, 11).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone,   SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        iRow = iRow + 1
    End If
Next i

iRow = 30
For Each i In Range("D2:D200")
    If i.Value = "-1CME Cash-Settled Butter" Then
        Range(i.Offset(0, 0), i.Offset(0, 3)).Copy
        Cells(iRow, 11).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
        iRow = iRow + 1
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: `cstr(i.Value) = "1CME Cash-Settled Butter"` Try this

Comment: Check if any of the cell has formula errors?

Comment: @Santosh, it worked!!!!!!!! You're awesome. Thanks so much! Do you think you could briefly explain why Cstr() works better? Should I replace my other loops using Cstr?

Comment: Welcome to SO, favoritewordgoeshere.

Comment: "1CME Cash-Settled Butter" is a string where as i is a range object. Cstr converts the value of range object to string and then you can make the comparison.

Comment: @favoritewordgoeshere: I see that you ignored my comment. I believe and I could be wrong but one of your cells have a formula error. Some thing like `#N/A` or `#DIV/0!` or something else. What `cstr(i.Value)` is doing is converting that to string. Another alternative is to use `If i.Text = "-1CME Cash-Settled Butter"`

Comment: @siddharthRout, I actually didn't have any formulas surrounding my data. They were all values. I will use i.Text. I apologize I didn't address your comment. Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `i.Value` to `i.Text`.  You don't want the Value, because you're comparing it to an integer.  You want to check the String, and using `i.Text` will do that.

You can also `cstr(i.Value)`, but that's not the best way to do it.